# Facebook auth always gives me long-lived access token. I don't want it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I use the Facebook PHP SDK to log in users on my website.

I was experimenting with the "long-lived" access token that expires after 2 months instead of 2 hours. Now I can't get rid of it. It is a problem for me, since it gives me access to the graph API even when the user is logged out of Facebook. I use that to determine if a user is logged in on my site, so it becomes impossible to log out.

I have tried changing the app ID and app secret, as well as deleting my facebook and app cookies, using other accounts, but nothing helps.

How can I get the 2 **hour** access token back, so I **can't** use the graph API when the user is not logged in?

Answer (score 1):

The server-side authentication flow will *always* give you a long-lived access token.

If you want a short-lived one, then you have to use the client-side flow (FB.login from the JavaScript SDK).

Comment: It didn't do that before... I had the 2 hour access token (verified in the debugger) until I asked for the long-lived one.

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation backing this up?

Comment: That client-side login gives a short-lived access token is in the description of deprecation of offline_access. But is says nothing about your scenario (having acquired long-lived token before) – but that’s not a general use case anyway, I’d say. Most developers want the long-lived version.

Comment: So, how would I log the user out?